# How to switch user in the server by su without password through shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, su

I am using cygwin to run my expect command for login into server. Once login i have to switch the user by su command writing password in the shell script which does not prompt for password and automatically switch user. I am not able to use expect command nor cannot use sudo, also configure any file.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host expect "assword" send "mypassword\r" interact
```

Comment: Show your expect script: [mcve]

Comment: Do not put your question in a comment.